# How can I use venv with SublimeREPL in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, windows, sublimetext3, sublimerepl, python-venv

For starters, here is my dev environment:

- Windows 7 (although I have the same issue on another machine that is Windows 10)
- Python 3.6
- Git Bash
- Sublime Text 3 (version 3.1.1, Build 3176)
- SublimeREPL

In Git Bash, I created a new virtual environment:

```
$ mkdir ~/.venv
$ cd ~/.venv
$ python -m venv test-env
```

To activate that virtual environment, I use:

```
$ source ~/.venv/test-env/Scripts/activate
```

**NOTE:** I had to modify the activate script (NOT activate.bat) to get the venv to activate properly. Specifically, I changed line 40 which looked something like:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="C:\Users\my_user_name\.venv\test-env"
```

to

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/c/Users/my_user_name/.venv/test-env"
```

Now, when I am in the test-env virtual environment (as evidenced by the "(test-env)" text in Git Bash), I can do the usual stuff like

```
(test-env)
$ pip install numpy
```

I also have the SublimeREPL package installed in Sublime Text 3. I setup a new build system (SublimeREPL-python.sublime-build) that looks like:

```
{
    "target": "run_existing_window_command", 
    "id": "repl_python_run",
    "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
}
```

Now, suppose I have a script

```
# test.py
import numpy as np


print('numpy was imported without error')
```

I can type Ctrl+Shift+B, then start typing 'repl', which autoselects the SublimeREPL-python build, then hit Enter. The SublimeREPL appears, but generates an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
>>>
```

SublimeREPL was called without using my virtual environment, which causes it to throw the error because numpy wasn't installed in my global python environment.

**How can I run my Python script from Sublime Text 3 using SublimeREPL and accessing my virtual environment that was created using venv?**

FWIW, I already tried creating a Sublime Project for this code and adding the following to the .sublime-project file:

```
"build_systems":
[
    {
        "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
        "name": "test-env",
        "selector": "source.python",
        "shell_cmd": "\"C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\.venv\\test-env\\Scripts\\python\" -u \"$file\""
    }
]
```

This allowed me to type Ctrl+Shift+B, then "test-env", then Enter (to build with the test-env build system I just created), which worked as expected and ran without error. However, it does not use SublimeREPL, which I'd like so that I can debug my code (which is more complicated that the simple test script I posted above!) and explore the variables in the REPL rather than just running code in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not an answer, but a partial solution that might help anyone else on same situation as I am. Also because [SublimeREPL support](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) is almost nothing.

**Note:** This solution requires to modify `Main.sublime-menu` for every environment and assumes SublimeREPL runs interactively already (adding the `"-i"` for execution).

1. **Browse packages** and open `SublimeREPL/config/python/Main-sublime-menu`.
2. Search for line with `"id": "repl_python_run"`.
3. Duplicate the nearest content inside the curly brackes.

Basically pasting after the same end bracket the following (note the `"-i"` option on `"cmd"` to run interactively):

```
{"command": "repl_open",
"caption": "Python - RUN current file",
"id": "repl_python_run",
"mnemonic": "R",
"args": {
   "type": "subprocess",
   "encoding": "utf8",
   "cmd": ["python", "-u", "-i", "$file_basename"],
   "cwd": "$file_path",
   "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
   "external_id": "python",
   "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
   }
},
```

4. **Change the id** `repl_python_run` to whatever you like, e.g., `repl_my_first_env_python`.
5. **Change python commmand** from `"cmd": ["python", "-u", "-i", "$file_basename"]` to use wherever your python's virtual environment executable is, e.g., `/home/me/.virtualenvs/my_first_env/bin/python` (linux example). **Save** the file.
6. **Edit project** to include inside the square brackets from `"build_systems"` the following:

(If you have no project, create a new `Build System` and paste next block of code)

```
{
    "name": "my first env",
    "target": "run_existing_window_command",
    "id": "repl_my_first_env_python",
    "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
},
```

7. Finally **Save**.

You'll see when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> you'll see `my first env` as an option.